# Mathematica: exporting to a variable path

Tags: variables, loops, wolfram-mathematica, quotes

this is tricky.
Once the path to export data in Mathematica is under quotes, how can I insert a variable as part of the path? In other words, I'm inside a loop that increments VAL and want to export MyData to VAL.dat. Ideas?

Pseudocode:
Export["~/Documents/VAL", MyData]

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Howard and Mr.Wizard's answers I could say that it would be good to look up `FileNameJoin` for a nice, system-independent way to compose path strings and `IntegerString` which you could use to convert integers to strings with a fixed number of positions, making your files sort more nicely:

```
In[33]:= VAL = 32;
IntegerString[VAL, 10, 4]

Out[34]= "0032"
```

I usually don't have much need for inter-OS compatibility (programming mostly for myself), so my usual style would be something like

```
Export["directoryPart\\FixedFileNamePart"<>IntegerString[VAL, 10, 4]<>".dat","TSV"]
```

Replace "TSV" with the file type you need if it isn't clear from the extension. Please note that I am on windows, which uses the backslash as separator. Since this is also the escape character, it has to be escaped with a backslash itself; this explains the double backslash. You seem to be on a UNIX derivate so there's no need for that. This does show the value of `FileNameJoin` which takes care of these details automatically.

Comment: +1 - I strongly agree with the suggestion of using `FileNameJoin`, `FileNameSplit` and friends. Regardless of whether you program "for yourself" or not, writing portable code is essential, since you never know which piece of your code will at some point be used by someone else.

Answer (score 4):

How about converting your number to string and join it with the path:

```
"~/Documents/"<>ToString[VAL]
```

Comment: great. It works if you also append the extension after val. I'm starting in mathematica! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to your question, you can use `StringReplace`:

```
Table[
  StringReplace[
     "~/Documents/#.dat", 
     "#" :> IntegerString[VAL, 10, 4]],
  {VAL, 27, 29}
]
```

```
   {"~/Documents/0027.dat", "~/Documents/0028.dat", "~/Documents/0029.dat"}
```

"#" was arbitrarily chosen as a placeholder.  Another character or string of characters could be used just as well.